# JavaScript fill missing keys in one JSON object from another JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object **object1** that needs to have missing fields filled from ***object2*** - existing fields should not be replaced.

I used to use this function:

```
function fillObject(from, to) {
    for (var key in from) {
        if (from.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(from[key]) === '[object Object]') {
                if (!to.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    to[key] = {};
                }
                fillObject(from[key], to[key]);
            }
            else if (!to.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                to[key] = from[key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked all the while both objects had the same structure. Now the *items* inside ***object1*** can actually appear anywhere in the structure. Example of ***object1*** and ***object2*** (structure might seem funny as I've removed all the unnecessary keys).

```
var object1 = [
    {
        "position": 1,
        "items": [
            { 
                "position": 1, "itemId": 431
            },
            {
                "position": 2, "itemId": 1162, "title": "Overwritten title"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "position": 2,
        "groups": [
            {
                "position": 1
                "items": [
                    {
                        "position": 1, "itemId": 452, "title": "New title"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 2, "itemId": 1388
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 3, "itemId": 1942
                    }
                ]
            },
            { 
                "position": 2, "itemId": 1942 
            },
            {
                "position": 3,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "position": 1, "itemId": 431
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 2, "itemId": 2000
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 3, "itemId": 452
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "position": 3, "itemId": 1388
    },
    {
        "position": 4, "itemId": 2000, "title": "Extra title"
    }
];

var object2 [
    { "itemId": 431, "title": "Title 1" },
    { "itemId": 452, "title": "Title 2" },
    { "itemId": 1162, "title": "Title 3" },
    { "itemId": 1388, "title": "Title 4" },
    { "itemId": 1942, "title": "Title 5" },
    { "itemId": 2000 }
];
```

And this is what I want the result to be:

```
var object1 = [
    {
        "position": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "position": 1, "itemId": 431, "title": "Title 1"
            },
            {
                "position": 2, "itemId": 1162, "title": "Overwritten title"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "position": 2,
        "groups": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "position": 1, "itemId": 452, "title": "New title"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 2, "itemId": 1388, "title": "Title 4"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 3, "itemId": 1942, "title": "Title 5"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "position": 2, "itemId": 1942, "title": "Title 5"
            },
            {
                "position": 3,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "position": 1, "itemId": 431, "title": "Title 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 2, "itemId": 2000
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 3, "itemId": 452, "title": "Title 2"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "position": 3, "itemId": 1388, "title": "Title 4"
    },
    {
        "position": 4, "itemId": 2000, "title": "Extra title"
    }
];
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals) might be helpful for you if you don't already know about them.

Comment: Could you use `itemId` property to uniquely identify an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you could identify object by a property (say `itemId`) you could do the following

- Split your task into small subtasks: copy missing property, traverse object structure, find corresponding source for an object
- Implement those small chunks of functionality as functions and use them together.

```js
const defaults = (target, src) => Object.keys(src)
  .forEach(key => key in target || (target[key] = src[key]))

const traverse = fn => traversable => {
  fn(traversable)
  
  const nested = Array.isArray(traversable) ? traversable : Object.values(traversable)  
  
  nested.filter(value => typeof value === 'object')
        .forEach(traverse(fn))
}

const fillById = id => sources => {
  const mapping = new Map(sources.map(item => [item[id], item]))
  
  return obj => {
    const src = mapping.get(obj.itemId)
    
    src && defaults(obj, src)
  }
}

var object1 = [
    {
        "position": 1,
        "items": [
            { 
                "position": 1, "itemId": 431
            },
            {
                "position": 2, "itemId": 1162, "title": "Overwritten title"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "position": 2,
        "groups": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "position": 1, "itemId": 452, "title": "New title"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 2, "itemId": 1388
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 3, "itemId": 1942
                    }
                ]
            },
            { 
                "position": 2, "itemId": 1942 
            },
            {
                "position": 3,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "position": 1, "itemId": 431
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 2, "itemId": 2000
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 3, "itemId": 452
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "position": 3, "itemId": 1388
    },
    {
        "position": 4, "itemId": 2000, "title": "Extra title"
    }
];

var object2 =  [
    { "itemId": 431, "title": "Title 1" },
    { "itemId": 452, "title": "Title 2" },
    { "itemId": 1162, "title": "Title 3" },
    { "itemId": 1388, "title": "Title 4" },
    { "itemId": 1942, "title": "Title 5" },
    { "itemId": 2000 }
];



traverse(fillById('itemId')(object2))(object1)

console.log(object1)
```

Comment: I'm getting *Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded* error on `mapping.get(obj.itemId);` when I try to run what you wrote.

Comment: My bad, it was from another piece of code I had added earlier.